# Can't modify vuex state through a mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex, apollo, vue-apollo

So I have this mutation in my store:

```js
DELETE_POST: (state, index) => {
  state.Posts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

and I also have this action:

```js
delete({ commit, state }, index) {
  commit('DELETE_POST', index);
}
```

This action basically deletes a post from an Array of posts, *that is returned through vue-apollo*.

Dispatching the action in my Vue component 
`this.$store.dispatch('Posts/delete', index);`

results in a **TypeError: 0 is read-only** error

Here's the state of the store:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  Posts: [] 
})
```

and the mutation responsible for setting posts:

```js
export const mutations = {
  SET_POSTS: (state, posts) => {
    state.Posts = posts;
  },
```

and here's how we fill the store via a graphql query using apollo client

```js
export const actions = {
  async get({ commit, state }, params) {
    let client = this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient;
    let { data: response } = await client.query({
      query: GetPostsQuery
      variables: {
        id: parseInt(params.id) || null,
        description: params.description || '',
        categoryId: params.categoryId || null,
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    });
    let postsDetails = response.Posts.get;
    if (postsDetails.status_code !== 200) return false;
      commit('SET_POSTS', postsDetails.data);
    return postsDetails.data;
  },
```

Is this a vue-apollo problem? and how could I possibly modify the state if so?

Comment: Need more info about `state.Posts` e.g. how you save posts to the store (probably `ADD_POST` mutation)

Comment: state should be an object, not a function, unless you're doing something extra that you're not showing.